# Onclick redirect with $_GET and Action

Tags: php

I have 2 radio buttons, and each does an action and redirects to that action. But I need it to keep my current page (or week in this case) so it redirects to the correct page.

I think I'm not using the php syntax correctly inside of the onclick.

```
echo ' <input type="radio" ' . (($spreads == 'yes') ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . ' onclick="window.location=\'' . ((!empty($_GET['week'])) ? '?week=' . (int)$_GET['week'] : '') . '\'&action=spreads\'"/><label>Show</label>' . "\n";
```

So it should get the week that the user is on, and redirect. So the URL would be something like: http://www.testsite.com/page.php?week=4?action=spreads

EDIT: I should have mentioned it was all inside of an echo to begin with.

EDIT 2: If i use a variable instead, it works just like I want it to. Very odd... I still would like to know how to use it without a variable.
Works:

```
$week_number = ((!empty($_GET['week'])) ? '?week=' . (int)$_GET['week'] : '');

//radio button
echo ' <td><input class="radio" type="radio" id="Show" ' . (($spreads == 'yes') ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . ' value="Show" onclick="location.href=\''.$week_number.'&action=spreads\'"/><label class="choice" for="Show">Show</label>' . "\n";
```

Comment: Do you think you could format your code so it does not need a scroll bar?

Comment: I removed some elements that don't really need to be there but I am not sure how to format it without a scroll bar without making it look very odd...

Answer (score 0):

You concat url-params with `&` and it must be `window.location` instead of `location.href`. So your code should be the following:

```
value="Show" onclick="window.location=\'' . ((!empty($_GET['week'])) ? '?week=' . (int)$_GET['week'] : '') . '\'&action=spreads\'"/><label class="choice" for="Show">
```

*And make sure to prepend the baseurl if you want to redirect to another url with given params.*

**EDIT**

I've edited my code again, because it seems that you are missing the opening single-quote before the url.
If this does not work too, please make sure to update your question with the full php echo for this specific line.

Comment: You are correct about using `&`, I had forgot about that. But with your code, I click the radio buttons and nothing happens. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you show me the output your PHP is generating (specifically the url)?

Comment: So for example, I'm using this elsewhere: `<a href="entry_form.php<?php echo ((!empty($_GET['week'])) ? '?week=' . (int)$_GET['week'] : ''); ?>">Make Picks</a>` and it works great, but I need to incorporate that same thing in to this onclick action. All it does is grab the week # and redirect on that.

Comment: I didn't mention it was all inside of an echo, and I updated my question. Here is just `<?php echo ((!empty($_GET['week'])) ? '?week=' . (int)$_GET['week'] : ''); ?>` this echos out to: `?week=4` but the `4` changes to whatever week the current user is looking at.

Comment: So my suggested edit with the opening single quote did not work?

Comment: Nope. I click the button and it doesn't do anything. No page refresh or anything.